# Inverse rotation matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, rotation

I guys,

I was wondering if this equality is true : Ra^-1.Rb^-1 = (Ra.Rb)^-1

Where Ra and Rb are two rotation matrix.

Does anybody have an idea to demonstrate this ?
Many thanks :)